# C# combining 2 reports

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I have 2 queries, with Parameters. I can get them to report individualy, however I want both tables on 1 report.  The problem is, a subreport seems to be problematic using parameters...  My 2 queries are:

```
SELECT        A.Store_Number, A.GC_Sold, B.Total_Cars

FROM            (SELECT        Store_Number, COUNT_BIG(Quantity_Sold) AS GC_Sold

FROM            Invoice_Detail_Tb

WHERE        (Invoice_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102)) AND (JLI_Category_Code = 'gc') AND (Invoice_Detail_Code LIKE 'jlgc%') AND (Invoice_Detail_Type = 'Item')

GROUP BY Store_Number) AS A INNER JOIN

(SELECT        Store_Number, SUM(Vehicle_Count) AS Total_Cars

FROM            Daily_Sales_Tb

WHERE        (Operations_Day BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102))

GROUP BY Store_Number) AS B ON A.Store_Number = B.Store_Number
```

This output gives me data for a date range and looks like this:

```
Store    gc sold      total cars
1        5             8
2        6             9
3        7             10
```

My Second query is:

```
SELECT        A.Store_Number, A.GC_Sold, B.Total_Cars

FROM            (SELECT        Store_Number, COUNT_BIG(Quantity_Sold) AS GC_Sold

FROM            Invoice_Detail_Tb

WHERE        (Invoice_Date = CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102)) AND (JLI_Category_Code = 'gc') AND (Invoice_Detail_Code LIKE 'jlgc%') AND (Invoice_Detail_Type = 'Item')

GROUP BY Store_Number) AS A INNER JOIN

(SELECT        Store_Number, SUM(Vehicle_Count) AS Total_Cars

FROM            Daily_Sales_Tb

WHERE        (Operations_Day = CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate, 102))

GROUP BY Store_Number) AS B ON A.Store_Number = B.Store_Number
```

This output returns data just for enddate. and looks identical to the table above.

The user is picking the startdate and enddate on a windows form and pushing "go".  The parameters are then passed to report viewer... Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder where is C# in this question?

Comment: you can shoot `query1 UNION ALL query2`  as single query

Comment: You can put your code in stored procedure with parameters and return one or two result set then put the data in the report view without passing parameters to the report

Comment: here is my C# code to pull the info for the first query... How can I get them to report to the same report in C#...   this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.JLI_DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.DataTable1,startdate.Value,enddate.Value);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

Comment: @Vlad, the c# bit will be "the user is picking the startdate and enddate on a windows form"

Comment: stored procedures are also a mess with report viewer using parameters.

Comment: @Bob: well, I see. I think we are missing tags `program`, `Windows`, .net-4.0`, `algorithm`, `user-interface`, `date`, `datetime` etc. as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a SQL Server Reporting Services report, then you can add multiple data sets. In your case, the first would use the first query, the second data set would use the second query with both data sets using the same shared data source (=> database connection).

Then you can add two tables to the report - one referencing the first data set as its data source, the other referencing the second data set.

The same can be modeled for local reports.

Comment: I get the error: Error 1 The Value expression for the textbox ‘textbox1’ uses an aggregate expression without a scope.  A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one data set.

Comment: This was using a second dataset.  Do I need to call it in the load of the report viewer?  Perhaps where it should be getting @enddate from?

Comment: Are we talking about a local report or a server side report? I need to know that before we continue.

Comment: It's server side reporting.  The user must have access to the network, as the datasource is referenced that way.

Comment: The error message most probably appears because you have _not_ (as I said in my reply) set the data source properly for the textbox. You must select the data set that contains the field you want to show.

Comment: are you refering to adding ", "Dataset1_Datatable1"" to the field after the .value?

Comment: No, I'm refering to setting the `DataSource` property for the control in the control's properties.

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'Fill' takes '2' arguments

Comment: The problem is, I think it's getting confused with the parameters... I only want the user to select 2 dates (datetimepicker1, datetimepicker2)

Comment: Actually it's trying to use the datatableadapter associated with the first dataset... How do I add it's OWN tableaddpter?

Comment: You said you had a server-side report - then you don't fill any data in the client. The report will obtain the data automatically.

Comment: I suppose it's not a server side report then.  My appologies.

Comment: I have figured it out.  I'll post the answer when i'm allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create another table addapter using the second query.  After you setup the next table adapter, you will need to add a table to the report viewer.  Once the table is added drag your fields from your new tableadapter to the table.  Once this is done, go to your reportviewer control, assign your new table a binding source for your dataset and